# PHP grab page with curl and click Submit button After a specified time

Tags: php, curl

i want to know what is the right way to click submit button After a specified time , Because the button Disable to click , but after 8 seconds Become Enabled !

here is my code to grab page

```
echo grab_page("http://www.exemple.com/form_to_submit.html");
function grab_page($site)
{
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $site);
   ob_start();
   return curl_exec ($ch);
   ob_end_clean();
   curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Comment: why not using javascript to trigger the click event after 10 seconds ?

Comment: Khalid can show me exemple code please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem using javascript like this :

```
echo "<script>

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('button_id').click();
    },10000);

</script>";
```

Comment: Khalid l3azz i will check it ;)

Comment: :) ! you just need to change the `'button_id'` to the id of your button

Comment: Khalid where i can put this code in the curl function & and can this click button on remote server ? !!

Comment: This code should be inserted inside the page, unfortunately if you don't own the page you can't do that programmatically, but you can do it manually by copying the code inside the `script` tag and pasting it in the browser's console when the page is loaded.